# Running a query to find Unique Records based on Table

Tags: ms-access

I have a table (tbl_finished_goods_Temp) that holds the following records;

```
STOCK_CODE
 5112120
 5112121
 5112132
 5112136
 5112176
 5112177
 5112235
 5112236
 5112237
 5112256
```

I have a query (qry_get_rid_of_non_unique_codes) that returns the following records;

```
StockCode      BomReference
 401006         5112177
 401006         5109094
 401006         5112236
 501377         5112120
 501376         5112120
```

I want to be able to create a query that returns StockCodes from qry_get_rid_of_non_unique_codes where the BomReference for a StockCode matches the STOCK_CODE field in tbl_finished_Goods_Temp.

The expected results would be as follows.

```
StockCode      BomReference
 501377         5112120
 501376         5112120
```

**Because 401006 has records in it other than what is in tbl_finished_goods_Temp, it won't pick it up.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out myself;

```
SELECT qry_unique_components_Step3.StockCode, *
FROM qry_unique_components_Step3
WHERE (((qry_unique_components_Step3.StockCode) Not In (SELECT qry_unique_components_Step3.StockCode
FROM qry_unique_components_Step3 LEFT JOIN tbl_finished_Goods_Temp ON qry_unique_components_Step3.BomReference = tbl_finished_Goods_Temp.STOCK_CODE
WHERE  tbl_finished_goods_Temp.STOCK_CODE Is Null)));
```

Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new query where you join the query `qry_get_rid_of_non_unique_codes` with the table `tbl_finished_goods_Temp` on BomRefernece = StockCode. Simple INNER JOIN.

**EDIT 2:**
Ah, alright. In that case, one way to do it is like this:

```
SELECT StockCode, BOMReference
FROM  qry_get_rid_of_non_unique_codes
WHERE StockCode NOT IN (
    SELECT StockCode FROM qry_get_rid_of_non_unique_codes WHERE BOMReference NOT IN (
        SELECT StockCode FROM tbl_finished_goods
    )
)
```

These are the codes you want to delete.

Comment: This still brings records for 401006. This is not what I want. If even one of the bomreferences doesn't appear in tbl_finished_goods_Temp then i don't want that StockCode to show up in my results.

Comment: Hmmm this doesn't seem to work for me.
I theory the following should work but the query takes literally a day to run. 

SELECT qry_unique_components_Step3.StockCode, qry_unique_components_Step3.BomReference
FROM qry_unique_components_Step3
WHERE qry_unique_components_Step3.StockCode NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT  qry_unique_components_Step3.StockCode FROM  qry_unique_components_Step3 WHERE  qry_unique_components_Step3.BomReference NOT LIKE 'BomReference');

Comment: This just returns a list of

 STOCK_CODE
 5112120
 5112121
 5112132
 5112136
 5112176
 5112177
 5112235
 5112236
 5112237
 5112256

Comment: Replace the outer tbl with the qry, i.e. `SELECT StockCode, BOMReference FROM qry_get_rid...` to also get the BOMs

Comment: This just returns all records from my qry

Answer (score 0):

As @Roland correctly ascertains as INNER JOIN projecting StockCode is all you need.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT StockCode 
FROM  tbl_finished_goods_Temp
INNER JOIN qry_get_rid_of_non_unique_codes 
ON    tbl_finished_goods_Temp.STOCK_CODE = qry_get_rid_of_non_unique_codes.BOMReference
```

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I'm not explaining myself well enough. Your query gives me a result for 401006 because it sees that a BomReference for the StockCode in qry_get_rid_of_non_unique_codes is in tbl_finished_goods_Temp which is what i'd expect... 

This is not what I want. what I want is for example; if 401006 has a  related BomReference which is not in that table(5109094), then 401006 gets totally deleted from my results. So no records with a StockCode of 401006 get returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the follwoing query:

```
SELECT StockCode 
FROM  tbl_finished_goods_Temp
INNER JOIN qry_get_rid_of_non_unique_codes 
ON    tbl_finished_goods_Temp.STOCK_CODE = qry_get_rid_of_non_unique_codes.STOCK_CODE
```